# Sorting Bigram by number of occurrence NLTK

Tags: python, nltk

I am currently running this code for search for bigram for entire of my text processing.

Variable alltext is really long text (over 1 million words)

I ran this code to extract bigram

```
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import re



tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'([A-za-z]{2,})')
tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(alltext)
stopwords_list = stopwords.words('english')
tokens = [word for word in tokens if word not in stopwords.words('english')]
finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(tokens, window_size = 2)
bigram_measures = nltk.collocations.BigramAssocMeasures()

for k,v in finder.ngram_fd.items():
    print k,v
```

The code above searches for the frequency occurrence for possible bigrams.

The code prints me lots of bigrams and its number of occurrence.

The output is similar to this.

```
(('upper', 'front'), 1)
(('pad', 'Teething'), 1)
(('shoulder', 'strap'), 1)
(('outer', 'breathable'), 1)
(('memory', 'foam'), 1)
(('shields', 'inner'), 1)
(('The', 'garment'), 2)
......

type(finder.ngram_fd.items()) is a list.
```

How can i sort the frequency from highest to lowest number of occurrence. My desire result would be.

```
(('The', 'garment'), 2)
(('upper', 'front'), 1)
(('pad', 'Teething'), 1)
(('shoulder', 'strap'), 1)
(('outer', 'breathable'), 1)
(('memory', 'foam'), 1)
(('shields', 'inner'), 1)
```

Thank you very much, I am quite new to nltk and text processing so my explanation would not be as clear.

Comment: use `for k,v in sorted(finder.ngram_fd.items(), key=lambda t:t[-1], reverse=True)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `finder.ngram_fd` is a dictionary. In that case, in Python 3 the `items()` method does not return a list, so you'll have to cast it to one.

Once you have a list, you can simply use the `key=` parameter of the [`sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) method, which specifies what we're sorting against:

```
ngram = list(finder.ngram_fd.items())
ngram.sort(key=lambda item: item[-1], reverse=True)
```

You have to add `reverse=True` because otherwise the results would be in ascending order. Note that this will sort the list **in place**. This is best when you want to avoid copying. If instead you wish to obtain a new list, just use the `sorted()` built-in function with the same arguments.

Alternatively, you can replace the lambda with [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)  module, which does the same thing:

```
ngram.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(-1), reverse=True)
```